# Trying to create 6 Months Rolling for current Month in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, microstrategy

I am trying to achieve the following layout. If I select curdate() which is june i should get previous 6 months.6 months should include June also .i.e. if curdate = june 25-2018 my out out should be months from June-2018 until Jan-2018. Can anyone please help me out with syntax. All I have now is individual queries which will give me previous 6 months in MYSQL.

Month   Previous Months 
june    may
        apr
        mar
        feb
        jan 
may     apr
        mar
        feb
        jan
        DEc

Comment: This is desired output.                                                                  Current Month   Previous Month
june                     May,Apr,march,feb,jan
may                     apr, mar, feb , jan , dec

Answer (score 0):

Use the Date_Add function. See examples below:

```
/* Query to select last 6 months (to the day) */
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    test_dates
WHERE 
    `date` > date_add(curdate(), INTERVAL -6 MONTH)



/* Query to get every date from 01/01/2018 to 06/25/2018 */
SELECT
    `date`
FROM
    test_dates
WHERE
    STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(`date`), '-', MONTH(`date`), '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d') 
    >= 
    STR_TO_DATE(
                CONCAT(
                        YEAR(DATE_ADD(curDate(), INTERVAL -5 MONTH)),
                        '-',
                        MONTH(DATE_ADD(curDate(), INTERVAL -5 MONTH))
                        , '-01'
                        )
                , '%Y-%m-%d'
                );
```

Code I used to setup test:

```
/* Create a table to test */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_dates;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_dates (
    `date` datetime
);


/* Insert Test Dates */
INSERT INTO test_dates (`date`) VALUES ('2018-06-01');
INSERT INTO test_dates (`date`) VALUES ('2018-05-01');
INSERT INTO test_dates (`date`) VALUES ('2018-04-01');
INSERT INTO test_dates (`date`) VALUES ('2018-03-01');
INSERT INTO test_dates (`date`) VALUES ('2018-02-01');
INSERT INTO test_dates (`date`) VALUES ('2018-01-01');
INSERT INTO test_dates (`date`) VALUES ('2017-012-01');
INSERT INTO test_dates (`date`) VALUES ('2017-011-01');
```